# making the same div operate independently

Tags: html, css

How can I take the same html and css and make them function independently Is my only option to copy the same code multiple times and add numbers too them to change the Id or class name. That's alto more code to add? 
Is there a simpler way?
Right now no matter which male and female button you click only the top one works. Im looking for css only.

```css
.plan input,
#msform .payment-plan input,
#msform .payment-type input {
  display: none;
}

label {
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #aaa;
  font-size: 26px;
  text-align: center;
  height: ;
  line-height: ;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.plan input:checked+label,
#msform .payment-plan input:checked+label,
#msform .payment-type input:checked+label {
  border: 2px solid #333;
  background-color: #2fcc71;
}

.plan input:checked+label:after,
msform .payment-plan input:checked+label:after,
#msform .payment-type input:checked+label:after {
  content: "\2713";
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  background-color: #2fcc71;
  z-index: 999;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  right: -10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="formwrap">
  <div id="ftx1">GENDER:</div>
  <section class="plan cf">
    <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="Male" value="Male"><label class="free-label four col" for="Male">Male</label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="Female" value="Female" checked><label class="basic-label four col" for="Female">Female</label>
  </section>
</div>

<div id="formwrap">
  <div id="ftx1">GENDER:</div>
  <section class="plan cf">
    <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="Male" value="Male"><label class="free-label four col" for="Male">Male</label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="Female" value="Female" checked><label class="basic-label four col" for="Female">Female</label>
  </section>
</div>

<div id="formwrap">
  <div id="ftx1">GENDER:</div>
  <section class="plan cf">
    <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="Male" value="Male"><label class="free-label four col" for="Male">Male</label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="Female" value="Female" checked><label class="basic-label four col" for="Female">Female</label>
  </section>
</div>

<div id="formwrap">
  <div id="ftx1">GENDER:</div>
  <section class="plan cf">
    <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="Male" value="Male"><label class="free-label four col" for="Male">Male</label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="Female" value="Female" checked><label class="basic-label four col" for="Female">Female</label>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: A **`for`** attribute belongs to an unique **`id`**.

Comment: IDs MUST be unique for this to work - they should always be unique anyway but in this case, it's a MUST

Comment: In plain english, IDs must be unique and in your code, you have multiple IDs that are the same so your radio is not working properly. Change the IDs and the corresponding `for` and it should work

Comment: As you can understand id is unique. Use class in order to style them the same instead.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear why you are trying to repeatedly add the same block of code. As you can see in [mozila's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) `id` is a global and unique attribute and, in each block, both divs are repeating it. It looks like what you're trying to achieve is the same as a [React Component](https://zhenyong.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html).